# Felling timber, tradition for a baronet?

Tags: literature

Everyone. I am reading some literature works recently. Here is my questions when I run into those words(excerpted from Lady Chatterley’s Lover):

> Sir Geoffrey stood for England and Lloyd George as his forebears had stood for England and St George: and he never knew there was a difference. So Sir Geoffrey felled timber and stood for Lloyd George and England, England and Lloyd George.

What is the real meaning for "felled timber", are there any subtexts in it, considering Geoffrey is a baronet?

Comment: If you mean did he chop wood, not likely. Maybe earthy, rugged, and patriotic. In the US, we'd say Mom and apple pie.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin That does make sense. I just wonder if it could be more definite.

Comment: See Kate's excellent answer.

Comment: You're reading this on the day that it (finally) is released from copyright protection in the USA.  (Happy PD day)

Comment: That's got to be one of the best 'damning praises' I've read in a long time. Sir Geoffrey is a patriot & a fool. He's forgotten the history of the landed gentry and its role in defending that land [with the blood of the poor, but never mind], & is instead following merely the current popular ruler. It's subtle… but it's deep. Lawrence has taken the glorious speech from Henry V & watered it down to apply to some parochial peer as he clears forest for a war he's not actually participating in. Clifford hates this attitude & is angry about the clearance. Eventually he has to fill those very shoes…

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth point the OP at [Literature.se].  If you're reading D.H.Lawrence, you're going to find a lot of subtle characterisation and allusions to aspects of 1920s British culture and class that are beyond "learning English". However, also remember that (as in this case) the answer is sometimes "read the novel", as the line here just references another part of the story.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not 'cut down trees' in person, but 'caused trees on his estate to be cut down'.

I found the passage from *Lady Chatterley's Lover* online, and discovered that a few paragraphs earlier it says that the trees were being felled to make 'trench props' - logs to reinforce the trenches on WW1 battlefields. Sir Geoffrey was being patriotic by supplying wood for the war effort.

Comment: Being 'patriotic' by selling lots of unwanted timber to the government at a profit, is I suspect the idea of contrasting St George and Lloyd George.

Comment: So happy there I got an answer. Really appreciate it.

Comment: David Lloyd George was the British Prime Minister during much of the first world war.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I see nothing to suggest the timber is "unwanted" - I'd have thought *any* such estate could always use timber. And I suspect characterizing Sir Geoffrey as motivated by *profit* just reflects your own position. I'm pretty sure there's nothing in the actual text to support it. And since his patriotism didn't distinguish between (liberal) LLoyd George and England itself, we should assume he was relatively "progressive" in his social outlook.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the family money came from mining, not forestry. Sir Geoffrey is noted as not being vaguely interested in the mines at all. There's a much deeper damnation of his attitude towards 'patriotism' which Clifford hates, as he does the clearance, yet has to take over the reigns of after Sir Geoffrey's demise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am willing to accept some of your criticism, to the extent that I will concede that Sir Geoffrey may not have been motivated entirely by profit. It is curious thing to read some of the numerous 'study notes' available on the web: _Before Christmas of 1914 both their German young men were dead: whereupon the sisters wept, and loved the young men passionately, but underneath forgot them._

Comment: *Sir Geoffrey, Clifford's father, was intensely ridiculous, chopping down his trees, and weeding men out of his colliery to shove them into the war; and himself being so safe and patriotic; but, also, **spending more money on his country than he'd got**.* And although we're told Clifford thinks everything is "ridiculous", I see nothing to suggest he replaced his father's patriotism with commercial  avarice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - one of the characters on BBC Radio 4's 'Gloomsbury' comedy series is 'DH Lollipop' who is taken up by the Gloomsbury set and says (or rather, shouts) things in a 'Nottinghamshire' accent like 'What the English upper classes need is some SEX-YEW-ALL INTERCOURSE!'.

Comment: I read it as presenting Sir Geoffrey’s patriotism as quite sincere (not cynically profit-motivated) but short-sighted and small-minded (clearing his woodlands gives a quick and visible bounty, good for both his personal gratification and social standing, but at the cost of a resource that takes generations to rebuild; meanwhile he neglects the mines which were an equally valuable and more sustainable contribution).